# Replace keyup event action with click event action

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Gn/23/

Rather than have `computedPageLinks` update via the search input `keyup` event, can anybody help me amend the above fiddle so `computedPageLinks` updates via a button `click` event and doesn't update when the search input loses focus?

Comment: It's not my work. I've changed the question slightly to better explain (hopefully)

Comment: Fair enough, I've put together an answer with an updated fiddle for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your search results are based on the value of `query` changing, even if you remove the `valueUpdate: 'keyup'` setting, that computed function will still update when the input box is blurred.

You can break that behavior by moving the "searching" out of the computed observable and instead populating a "results" observable array when the click occurs.

So, add a "results" array:

```
self.results = ko.observableArray([]);
```

And then add a search function we can trigger on click that populates the results:

```
self.search = function() {
    // Did the user search for anything?
    if (!self.query()) {
        self.results([]);
        return;
    }
    // Do the "search"
    self.results(ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pageLinks(), function(item) {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }) || []);
};
```

Now you can remove the computed observable, and change your binding to use the `results` array:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: results">
```

To link it all up, first remove the `valueUpdate` setting on your `<input>` and add a `<button>` that triggers the `search` function on your model:

```
<input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query" autocomplete="off" /> 
<button type="button" data-bind="click: search">Go</button>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Gn/25/)